# Countif with multiple criterias in R

Tags: r, if-statement, count

I would like to count all rows where two criterias are matched. My approach was:

```
a <- c(2,1,2,2,3,4,2,1,9)
b <- c(2,1,2,1,4,4,5,6,7)
c <- data.frame(a,b)
sum((c['a']==2) && (c['b']==2))
```

but for some reason this gives 1 instead of two. How could I count rows if multiple criterias are matched?

Comment: `&` is vectorized, `&&` evaluates only the first match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong ampersand operator. Try this:

```
sum(c['a']==2 & c['b']==2)
[1] 2
```

If you might have NAs in column a or b you might also try:

```
length(intersect(which(c['a']==2), which(c['b']==2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also subset within the `data.frame` and then find the rows for it.

```
nrow(c[a==2 & b==2, ])
# [1] 2
```

P.S : It is advised not to use `c` as a variable as it is also a base R function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's just named c in the example, in real i has a better name ;-)