# Count character rows meeting multiple criteria in R

Tags: r, count, sum

I am trying to count the number of rows which meet multiple criteria (criteria in different columns) in R on a large dataset and am having some trouble getting the results I want.

Example dataframe:

```
LU <- c("A", "A", "P", "P", "A", "G", "A", "G") 
Type <- c("one", "one", "one", "three", "two", "three", "one", "two") 
Style <- c("C-acq", "C-acq", "C-acq", "N-acq", "C-acq", "Ox", "C-acq", "N-acq")
df <- data.frame(LU, Type, Style)
```

To count the number of apples, that are num 1, and location A-01, I've tried this:

```
length(intersect(which(df1['LU']=="A", which(df['Type']=="one"))))
```

but can't get it to work/get an error saying the "selecting method for function 'which': undefined columns selected". The sum function works on this mock data but when I try to apply it to my own data it seems to just be adding up the number of rows which fall into any of the criteria I listed (instead of adding up the number of rows based on the criteria I applied) or says NA (which I know isn't correct).

sum function I've used (works on this mini data but not on my data):

```
sum(df1$LU == "A" & df1$Type == "one" & df1$Style == "C-acq")
```

Is there another way to count the number of rows meeting multiple criteria? (not sure how to get the count function to do this). I think a problem with my data is that rows may have NA values which may be interfering with the sum function.

I know there are a lot of questions about stuff like this (other threads listed below) so am sorry if this a redundant question but cannot find an answer that works for my data. Thanks for the help!

Count with table output

[Rows meeting multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468795/count-number-of-rows-meeting-multiple-conditions-in-dataframe)

[Countif in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355300/countif-with-multiple-criterias-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we need to extract as a `vector` with `[[` or add a `,` (with `tibble/data.table` it may not work though) or use `$`.  Also, the first `which` is not closed

```
length(intersect(which(df[['LU']]=="A"), which(df[['Type']]=="one")))
#[1] 3
```

In addition, the syntax shows `df` and `df1` as object names whereas the example object is 'df'

---

Or we can also use `subset` with `nrow`

```
nrow(subset(df, LU == "A" & Type == "one"))
#[1] 3
```

If there are `NA` elements, either add `& !is.na(LU) & !is.na(Type)` or use `%in%` as `%in%` returns FALSE for NA elements whereas `==` returns `NA`

```
nrow(subset(df, LU %in% "A" & Type %in% "one"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!